# MVC Login Form - Resource not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to implement my own login framework which originated from my ASP.NET projects and is now about to migrate to ASP.NET MVC.

**The Problem**

Whenever I click the submit button in `CommunityBar.cshtml` I am redirected to: `localhost/Home/Login?Length=4` and receive a `resource not found error` but having spent the last few hours on this problem, together with our handy friend, google, I have yet to find a solution. So I was hoping somebody here might be able to help.

Next a bunch of code:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
// POST home/login
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Home/Login/{model}/{returnUrl}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
    );
```

**CommunityBar.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {role = "form"}))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginUsername, new {@class = "form-input", @placeholder = "Username"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginUsername, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPassword, new {@class = "form-input", @placeholder = "Password"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginPassword, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     @Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "Home", new {@class = "form-btn"})
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(UserViewData model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return Content("test");
    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

**UserViewData Model**

```
public class UserViewData
{

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LoginUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

    public MembershipUser User { get; private set; }
    public bool HasMessages { get; private set; }
    public List<MembershipUserPrivateMessage> Messages { get; private set; }
    public bool HasNotifications { get; private set; }
    public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; private set; }

    public UserViewData(MembershipUser user)
    {
        UserService userService = new UserService();

        this.User = user;
        this.HasMessages = userService.CountUnreadPrivateMessages() > 0;
        this.Messages = userService.GetPrivateMessages(false).Where(p => !p.IsRead).Take(5).ToList();
        this.HasNotifications = false;
        this.Subscriptions = null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: One possible solution, is to avoid the POCO structure**

RouteConfig.cs

```
// POST home/login
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Home/Login/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
);
```

CommunityBar.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-input" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="text" name="password" class="form-input" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
// POST: /Home/Login
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Content("fail");
    }

    return Content("success" + username + password);
}
```

I personally don't like this, as this is really just a way to hide the problem than an actual solution. So I'm gonna keep this Question alive, if somebody figures our what the problem is with the original code. Or I do...

Comment: @Div, Should perhaps have mentioned, that I have tried without the route. No success...

Comment: In your route I can see a {model} parameter which does not seem to be provided in your URL. Try removing {model} from the route and see if that helps.

Comment: @Vahid, same result unfortunately.

Comment: Could it not just be because there is no submit button, but an anchor link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RouteConfig.cs is fine in this format.

```
// POST home/login
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "Home/Login/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
);
```

CommunityBar.cshtml has no way to submit the form as the action link in the OP renders an action tag that just links back to the page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {role = "form"}))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginUsername, new {@class = "form-input", @placeholder = "Username"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginUsername, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPassword, new {@class = "form-input", @placeholder = "Password"})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginPassword, "", new {@class = "danger"})
     <!-- Remove action link and add Submit button here -->
     <button class="form-btn" type="submit">Sign In</button> 
}
```

UserViewData Model needs a parameter less constructor to allow model binder to create model on post. currently it requires dependency. Also looks like this model has multiple roles. Use a simple POCO.

```
public class LoginModel {    
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LoginUsername { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs needs to make sure it is passing the model on the original get

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login() {
    var model = new LoginModel();//also why default constructor needed
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    //...login logic here

    //if reach this far then redirect
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl)) {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    } else {
        return this.RedirectToAction("MyActionNameHere");
    }
}
```

Comment: Reg. the UserViewData, I need to pass quite a bit of information to the same view. Hence the reason I combined the "LoginModel" into the UserViewData. Would I still need to do that with your LoginModel ? (I dont know if I made myself clear enough in this comment)

Comment: No not clear yet. examples shows a very simplified view. answer was based on that

Comment: To incorporate the need for essentially two models, your "LoginViewModel" and my UserViewData. Can I make this into its own "Combined"ViewModel, so I have both the data I need and the LoginViewModel needed by the form ? Afterwhich, will the form still work ?